# MongoDB Update N first elements in array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the yesterday price history in MongoDB collection:

```
{
 ticker: 'APPL':
 hist: [{'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0),
         'Close': 10.58,
         'Volume': 71055},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 0, 0),
         'Close': 10.28,
         'Volume': 89012},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 0, 0),
         'Close': 10.26,
         'Volume': 12198}
        }]
}
```

and today I have updated price:

```
 {
'AAPL': [{'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 16, 0, 0),
         'Close': 9.78,
         'Volume': 8214},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0),
         'Close': 11.03,
         'Volume': 71033},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 0, 0),
         'Close': 10.25,
         'Volume': 89026}]
}
```

The expected result:

```
{
 ticker: 'APPL':
 hist: [{'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 16, 0, 0),
         'Close': 9.78,
         'Volume': 8214},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0),
         'Close': 11.03,
         'Volume': 71033},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 14, 0, 0),
         'Close': 10.25,
         'Volume': 89026},
        {'Time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 0, 0),
         'Close': 10.26,
         'Volume': 12198}
        }]
}
```

How to update the existing date and insert the new date the collection without deleting the n-first array first?
Another example, I have the 1-year length array of data, but I need to update the last 7 days in the array and also add today's data.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you want to update only date or total document? looks like all the values are changed

Comment: @deadshot the total document, I guess, the example, I have the 1-year length array of data, but I need to update the last 7 days in the array and also add today's data.

Comment: you want to update first document with second one?

Comment: @deadshot yes! I will add the expected result int the description.